# pv console utility brokes ansi-term

Tags: ansi-term

Every time I use pv in ansi-term it brokes my terminal. There are two possibilities:

1. broken terminal clears every time i press enter and hides output
2. it stops understand \n or something and writes output line by line in a bottom of a window, overwriting previous line by next.

How do I fix this? Why this doesn't happening in regular terminals like gnome-terminal? Is it a pv bug or something emacs-specific?

Comment: Does this issue still occur when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, please try to [bisect your init file](//meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/204/675).